# Laravel Eloquent updateOrCreate using pre-populated model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Throughout the code, I am populating an eloquent model by getting data from API calls. After I have populated the model I go to save it but there's a chance it may exist in the database (primary ID).

It seems silly to populate a model like so:

```
$lead = new Lead;
$lead->id = '123';
$lead->name = 'Tom';
$lead->address = '121 main st';
```

Then have to do this to use updateOrCreate:

```
    $lead = Lead::updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $lead->id],
        [
          'name ' => $lead->name,
          'address ' => $lead->address,
        ]
    );
```

I've also tried:

```
$lead = new Lead;
$lead = Lead::find($place);
$lead->id = '123';
$lead->name = 'Tom';
$lead->address = '121 main st';
$lead->save();
```

But of course, that does not work because if the lead does not exists you get back a null object and can't create a default object from an empty value.

Comment: Why do you insert a primary key? Shouldn't it be `AUTO_INCREMENT`? To check if it exists, use `find()` function like you do. Then, you will need if-else conditions to get the rest done.

Comment: Why would you need both?  I don't see why your first code block would be necessary/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second code, you're overwriting the `$lead`. What you'd want is `firstOrNew()`

```
$lead = Lead::firstOrNew(123);
$lead->name = 'Tom';
$lead->address = '121 main st';
$lead->save();
```

You can also try with this method:

```
if(!$lead = Lead::find(123)) {
   $lead = new Lead();
   $lead->id = 123;
}
$lead->name = 'Tom';
$lead->address = '121 main st';
$lead->save();
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. However I believe you need to do: $lead = Lead::firstOrNew(['id' => '123']);

Answer (score 2):

So aynber's solution will work fine but your logic seems strange to me.  What is the point of populating a new model prior to running updateOrCreate?

Just use updateOrCreate with the request data:

```
$lead = Lead::updateOrCreate(
    ['id' => '123'],
    [
      'name ' => 'Tom',
      'address ' => '121 main st',
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the object first :

```
$lead = Lead::find($place);

if( is_null($lead) ) {
  $lead = new Lead;
}

$lead->name = 'Tom';
$lead->address = '121 main st';

$lead->save();
```

`$lead->save()` here will work for new and existing objects.

**NOTE:** `id` should be added dynamically in the case of new `Lead`.